# Dense symmetric unitary integer matrix?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Can someone give me a nontrivial example of a symmetric unitary integer matrix?  I'm looking for something as dense as possible (i.e., not too many 0's); 5 <= size <= 8 would be ideal.

Comment: You can't expect a matrix to be dense *and* unitary *and* integer. If it's unitary, all of its rows and columns have norm one, which means (since the entries are integers) they have at most one non-zero entry. The identity matrix, permutation matrices, and their obvious modifications are the only integer unitary matrices that exist.

Answer (score 1):

Bazillions of such matrices are given by [Householder Reflections.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) Enjoy! (but the only integral orthogonal matrices are the signed permutation matrices, which are not dense, sadly). In fact, in your case, the square of this matrix is the identity, so the associated permutation is a product of (disjoint) transpositions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Umm, how is your comment a *a propos*? Householder matrices are unitary hermitian (the parenthetical remark addresses your concern).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Umm, I do talk about in the parenthetical remark.

Comment: @ChristianRemling True, *mea culpa*